# Django Migrations not detecting is_active column

Tags: django, django-models

I created a custom user model using the AbstractBaseUser class (see source code below). However, after realising that the column I needed in the table should be called "is_active" not "active", I renamed the column in the models file, however, the migrations only removed the "active" column but didn't create an "is_active" column. Any ideas?

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a admin user; non super-user
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    manager_access = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # Email & Password are required by default.
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.is_superuser

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.is_active
```

Comment: Did the migration really just remove `active`, or did it maybe rename it to `is_active`?

Comment: No it removed the column but didn't rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing this chunk of code:

```
  @property
def is_active(self):
    "Is the user active?"
    return self.is_active
```

After doing this and rerunning the migrations, the is_active column was added.